# Deleted user accounts and database by mistake, how to recover it?

Tags: mysql, database, privileges, recovery, disaster-recovery

I was trying to change my phpmyadmin username and password in the sql query using the code below, but it deleted all of my databases and user accounts.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET user='newusername',
password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

What can I do to recover the possible best state of my system?

Comment: I don't think this command deleted your accounts and databases. Why do you think they are deleted?

Comment: Good to know, but what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

This query renames all `root` user to `newusername`, and sets their password to `root`. It doesn't change any other databases, neither deletes anything.

Your databases should be still there.

`ls /var/lib/mysql` can show, which dbs are *really* existing.

The old passwords of the `root` user are gone, but a rough reversion of its username can be reached by an

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET user='root' WHERE user='newusername';
```

query.

If you can't start your mysql server, stop the server, and temporarily restart it with

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

In this mode, the mysql entirely bypasses all authentication. More can you read from it [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password).

Answer (score 0):

If your database has been deleted, you cannot restore it, it is better to create a new database.
If you have actually deleted one of the database tables, its file manually; If you know about its fields, you can return it, otherwise you have to create a new database again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).